# Dark current of photodiode gets higher after heating, why?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, photodiode

I'm doing some experiments using photodiodes. I raised the temperature to about 1000 degree Celsius for 1 second with melting AuSn near the PIN junction. Then the dark current of photodiode is higher than before. What are the causes? Is the photodiode broken?

PS:
more info.

1. I'm using Si photodiode.
2. It's the heating plate that reaches 1000 C, temperature around PIN junction is about 500 C. my mistake.

Comment: Describe exactly how you raised the temperature to 1000 degrees for one second. Did you touch it with a 1000 degree probe for 1 second? Did it sit in an oven that slowly raised up to 1000 degrees and then turned off? Did you hit it with a 1000 degree heat gun for 1 second?

Comment: @Dan Laks. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the question.

Comment: Woah, 1000 C, I have no idea, but all sorts of dopant's, contacts, metals could diffuse around.  Ask the manufacturer.

Comment: I'm not a materials guy, but I seem to recall that gold has a tendency to diffuse into devices and muck things up. I'm going to guess you contaminated your device with gold.

Comment: @ThePhoton, George: Thanks! Are there machines that can check the contamination?

Answer (score 1):

There are, no doubt, many reasons why the dark current increased, but to answer the question about whether the diode is broken - badly or otherwise - it's just necessary to measure the current with the diode illuminated. If you're using the diode in reverse-biased mode,   measuring the reverse current with various levels of illumination will give you some idea of how its response conforms to the data sheet specifications.

If you're using it in photovoltaic mode, then subjecting it to various levels of illumination and load and plotting its response as a load line will also yield salient data.

In the real world, though, if you've exceeded the manufacturer's maximum temperature spec by what... six or seven times? I'd say you've definitely let the magic smoke out.

Answer (score 1):

First off, AuSn solders have a Eutectic point of around 300 C.  As to how hot any junctions got, that is dependant upon materials (which you don't mention) is is Si, InGaAs, GaAs etc. etc.

A PIN photodiode relies on a very lightly doped Intrinsic region so raising the temperature raises the solid solubility and mobility of dopants.  In Si junction tend to start moving around 900 C ( as a rule of thumb) but again, you don't say what the system is and you don't really indicate why you think you spiked it to 1000C.

On the other hand, any dopant migration into the intrinsic region will adversely affect the leakage.

If you mechanically stressed the die that can possibility also affect mobility and leakage current.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Si photodiode. I do the experiment again. It's the heating plate that reaches 1000 C, temperature around PIN junction is about 500 C.